# iphone: how to code different label for each image in scrollview

Tags: iphone, nsarray, label, scrollview

I successfully created a UIscrollview (horizontal) for 50 images and also created a label of "1 of 50" page number displaying at the top of the image along with the scroll view(for example user scroll to next image it would show 2 of 50, 3 of 50, so forth). I am able to display a label at the bottom of the image as a description. My problem is how can I create or code to display different description for each image? Im thinking of NSarray but it shows some random numbers. Is there a sample I can look at to see what I am doing wrong. you can see the description part where I am lost from there. Thanks =)

```
    CGFloat xOffset = 0;
        NSInteger pageNumber = 1;
            NSUInteger i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"creative%d.jpg", i];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

            [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, 0, 320, 288.5)];
            [ourScrollView addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];

            UILabel *pageNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, -10, 320, 40)];
            [pageNumberLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of 5", pageNumber]];
            [pageNumberLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
            [pageNumberLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                    [pageNumberLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                    [pageNumberLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:18]];
            [ourScrollView addSubview:pageNumberLabel];
            [pageNumberLabel release];

  NSArray  *description = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"wow", @"bam", @"pow", @"zing", @"bling",nil];                 

                    UILabel *descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, 250, 320, 40)];
                    [descriptionLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", description]];
                            [descriptionLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
            [descriptionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                    [descriptionLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [ourScrollView addSubview:descriptionLabel];
            [descriptionLabel release];

            xOffset = xOffset + 320;
            pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
```

Comment: "Im thinking of NSarray but it shows some random numbers." -- What do you mean by that??

Comment: sorry it was the %d that made up the random number i just updated my post with "%@"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the descriptionLabel with a format of `@"%d"`, which is a decimal format.  What is "description"?  If it's a NSString then you should be using `@"%@"`.

Comment: Just updated my post with the correct format. as you can see with 5 diff. labels in the array It display all the labels in all images. I would like to know how to take the first label for the first image and second label for second image...etc =) thanks!

Comment: Well, I can't see, because you're not showing us the results, nor any info on what "description" is.  Is "description" a single string, a C array, an NSArray, what?  If it's an array, you need to (duh!) index it -- `[i]` or `objectAtIndex:i`.

Comment: description as in sentence explaining what the image showing. I've tested with array but its showing all the label in the array instead of first label for first image and so on. I still feel like I am missing something here but couldn't figure it out

Comment: description is an NSArray.  It needs to be indexed.  You index an NSArray with objectAtIndex.

Comment: can you give me sample of that please

Comment: (Sigh) `[descriptionLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [description objectAtIndex:i - 1]];`.  Was that hard?

Comment: it works thanks! my mistake was I put 1 instead of negative 1. Can you explain the diff. I search and found some vague answers its not straightforward. Thanks again Daniel i'll accept the answer =)

Comment: Your loop index starts with 1.  An array is, in most languages (including Objective-C), indexed from zero.  So you subtract 1 from your loop index to come up with the array index.